# Replace href with link text/name

Tags: php, href

I have a string in php with many a tags... See below for more clerification

It is like ....  bla bla   bla bla bla bla

`<a href="test.php">link1</a'>  hellllo`

`<a href="test.php">link2</a> hiiiiiiiiii`

My problem is I want to replace href i.e test.php with link1,link2,link3 .... so on.

Kindly help.  ' ' are added for show only consider them as proper links

Comment: Can you post the code to clarify?

Comment: it goes like <tr>
            <div style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;"><span style="font-size: medium;"><a href="act_rules.html?id=1170">Valuation of taxable services for charging service tax</a></span></div>
            </td>
        </tr>

I want to replace act_rules.html with its value which is "Valuation of taxable services for charging service tax"

Thank you for considering

Comment: Wby would you want the link anchor as the href, pointing to an invalid destination surely? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: this link1,2,3 are not static .. they could be a string of 5,10,15 .... cherecter .. means not static .. it keep on changing .. so not possible in this way .. do you have another solution ?

Answer (score 2):

use DOMDocument and friends:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Something like this, but unsure as it is untested, and I am only going off documentation.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($input_string);
$link_list = $xml->getElementsByTagName('a');
$link_list_length = $link_list->length;
for ($i = 0; $i < $link_list_length; $i++) {
    $attributes = $link_list->item($i)->attributes;
    $href = $attributes->getNamedItem('href');
    $href->value = $link_list->item($i)->nodeValue;
}
$output_string = $xml->saveHTML();
```

Comment: @miurvictim glad I could help. if this is the solution that solved your issue, you may want to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. this helps the next person who finds this post with a similar issue.

Comment: @miurvictim it should be directly under the voting number to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, **do not** use regular expressions. It might work for a bit, but down that path lies madness.

What you want to do is **parse** the string into XML using PHP's "DOM" library. This converts the HTML (assuming it is valid HTML and not malformed) into a set of objects that you can navigate, modify, and then convert back into a string later.

You can find several guides on the web, like [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/).

This is purely off-the-cuff code, I have not tested it, but it should give you a general idea:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($YOUR_DATA); 
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "a" );
foreach( $links as $link )
{
    // Modify $link however you need to
}
$CONVERTED_DATA = $doc->saveHtml();
```